# Nodemailer shows emails in the browser instead of sending them

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm trying to use the email-templates package but I ran into a problem. Everything was working fine until I changed the path from a static file to a url. From then, whenever I try to send an email, it just shows the temp file in the browser instead of actually emailing anything. I tried changing it back but the problem is still here. Since this is about the attachments, I'm assuming it's a nodemailer problem, not an email-templates problem.
Here's my code:

```
const Email = require("email-templates");
email = new Email({
    message: {
        from: "pribehytest@seznam.cz"
    },
    // uncomment below to send emails in development/test env:
  // send: true
  transport: {
    host: "smtp.seznam.cz",
       port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "mail",
        pass: "password"
    }
  }
})

// this is in a different file
pdf.create(compiledPugInvoice({
    // some locals
}), {format: "Letter"}).toFile("emails/newOrder/invoices/invoice" + orderID + ".pdf", (err, result) => {
    if(err) next(err);
    else{

        cloudinary.uploader.upload("emails/newOrder/invoices/invoice" + orderID + ".pdf", (cloudinaryResult) => {
            console.log(cloudinaryResult);

            // send an email to the client
            email
                .send({
                    template: "newOrder",
                        message: {
                            to: req.body.email,
                                attachments: [
                                    {
                                        filename: "faktura.pdf",
                                        path: cloudinaryResult.secure_url
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                        locals: {
                            // some locals
                            }
                        })
                            .then(() => {
                                fs.unlink("emails/newOrder/invoices/invoice" + orderID + ".pdf", (err) => {
                                    if(err) next(err);
                            }))
                            .catch(console.error);

                        });
```

Comment: Does it also happend if you run your app with `NODE_ENV=production`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `preview : false` to your `email` instance

Like this

```js
email = new Email({
  message: {
    from: "pribehytest@seznam.cz",
  },

  send: false, // Change this to true if you want to actually send the email
  preview: false, // This will not open the browser

  transport: {
    host: "smtp.seznam.cz",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "mail",
      pass: "password",
    },
  },
})
```